# How to connect to SSH-server over TOR-network?

Tags: ssh, tunnel

On host1 (server) : `sshd` with config

```
Port 56320
AllowUsers user11123

AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 127.0.0.1

TCPKeepAlive yes
Compression delayed

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server

KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa
HostbasedAuthentication yes
HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes

AuthorizedKeysFile /home/user11123/.ssh/authorized_keys

PermitRootLogin no
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes

ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 5

SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
```

and `tor` with

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/ssh/
HiddenServicePort 56320 127.0.0.1:56320
```

iptables disabled.

on host2 : `tor` and `ssh nb` with config

```
host nb
    User user11123
    Hostname __copy_addr_from_host1__.onion
    Port 56320
    VerifyHostKeyDNS no
    ProxyCommand ncat -vvv --proxy 127.0.0.1:9050 --proxy-type socks5 %h %p

KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa
HostbasedAuthentication yes
HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa
PasswordAuthentication no
CheckHostIP no

KeepAlive yes
```

and result is :

```
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
NCAT DEBUG: Using system default trusted CA certificates and those in /usr/share/ncat/ca-bundle.crt.
Ncat: Connected to proxy 127.0.0.1:9050
Ncat: No authentication needed.
Ncat: Error: Host unreachable.
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

`tor.log` on host2 :

```
Close 1 streams for service [scrubbed].onion for reason resolve failed. Fetch status: No more HSDir available to query.
```

please tell me how to set it up

Answer (score 0):

I have done it through proxy connect in Ubuntu. You may check my blog post, section Remote Control Alternatives for the steps.

https://mstajbakhsh.ir/control-home-iot/

[image: connect to ssh through hidden service]

Comment: i have 56-character address ( version 3 )

Comment: I think that this is the problem

Comment: `tor-resolve ysevcxugbwb5n57ltjtpaimnoqjdb6lhte3neasiniusyqd55tvjnayd.onionfe81:f7fa:5793:4e13:5181:f2cf:a5ba:d5fc`

Comment: `torsocks curl $(tor-resolve ysevcxugbwb5n57ltjtpaimnoqjdb6lhte3neasiniusyqd55tvjnayd.onion)
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Comment: Does tor-resolve uses version 3 of TOR? Because the 56 chars are supported in version 3.

Comment: tor version 0.4.0.5